# WooCommerce - how to retrieve current orderby/sorting selection?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to retrieve the current order of products (as ids) on the shop page for further use. Sorting is done via the standard dropdown (date, price: low to high, price: high to low).

Using $orderby, I can manage this for date and price ASC. But the value of $orderby is the same for price ASC and DESC. How can I correctly retrieve the current value for each sorting option?

```
if ($orderby == 'date ID') {
  $ordertype = 'date';
  $meta = '';
  $order = 'desc';
}
elseif ($orderby == 'price')  {
  $ordertype = 'meta_value_num';
  $meta = '_price';
  $order = 'asc';
}

$query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
 'limit' => -1,
 'orderby'        => $ordertype,
 'meta_key'       => $meta,
 'order'          => $order,
 'return'         => 'ids',
) );

$products = $query->get_products();

print_r($products);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your standard dropdown needs to be in this order.

HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="low_to_high">Low to High</option>
    <option value="high_to_low">High to Low</option>
</select>
```

and based on selection your condition will be.

PHP

```
<?php 

if ($orderby == 'low_to_high') {
    $ordertype = 'meta_value_num';
    $meta      = '_price';
    $order     = 'asc';
}elseif ($orderby == 'high_to_low') {
    $ordertype = 'meta_value_num';
    $meta      = '_price';
    $order     = 'desc';
}else{
    $ordertype = 'date';
    $meta      = '';
    $order     = 'desc';
}

$query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
    'limit'    => -1,
    'orderby'  => $ordertype,
    'meta_key' => $meta,
    'order'    => $order,
    'return'   => 'ids',
) );

$products = $query->get_products();

print_r($products);

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! The option values are named differently however by default. I was finally able to to get to the information though: $orderby_value = $_GET['orderby'] - by using  $orderby_value instead of $orderby, it works for me